# TypeScript new Array.prototype Generic Function with 'this' parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, generics, this

I have an Angular 8/TS app, and I'd like to add a `.groupBy()` function to Array's prototype. I have read up on the TypeScript [this parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html), which states that you just add `this: <Type>` as a fake first parameter to your argument.

This works splendidly *inside* the method as I'm defining it for the prototype, but anywhere I *call* the method, my array reverts to type `any`.

So my problem is, I think, that I'm using an Array (which is generic), and my function takes generic parameters, like so:

```
if(!Array.prototype.groupBy) {
    Array.prototype.groupBy = function<T, TKey, TResult>(
        this: T[], // here's the magical "this" parameter
        keySelector: (item: T) => TKey,
        itemSelector: (item: T) => TResult
    ): Group<TResult, TKey>[] {
```

I have a test method in the same file that calls my new method:

```
function test(): void {
    let arr: number[] = [ 11, 29, 32, 33, 10, 55 ];
    let groupByTens = arr.groupBy(
        i => i / 10, // here, "i" is "unknown" which generates a compile error
        i => i.toString());
}
```

If I am explicit when I call `arr.groupBy<number, number, string>(..)`, then it works find, but I don't want to have to explicitly state the generic types. **How can I write my "extension method" in such a way that I won't have to explicitly state the generic types?**

Thanks!

And for completeness's sake, here's my full groupBy function:

```
if(!Array.prototype.groupBy) {
    Array.prototype.groupBy = function<T, TKey, TResult>(
        this: T[],
        keySelector: (item: T) => TKey,
        itemSelector: (item: T) => TResult
    ): Group<TResult, TKey>[] {
        let groupDict: any = {};

        // HERE, if I provide the "this parameter", then "this" is an Array<T>. If I don't,
        // then "this" is an "any". So the "this parameter" is working just fine inside the
        // function declaration.
        this.forEach((item: T) => {
            let groupKey = keySelector(item);

            let group = groupDict[groupKey];
            if (!group) {
                group = new Group<TResult, TKey>(groupKey);
                groupDict[groupKey] = group;
            }

            group.members.push(itemSelector(item))
        });

        return Object.keys(groupDict)
            .map(key => <Group<TResult, TKey>>groupDict[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just had a look at the `Array.prototype.concat` function in VSO. The intellisense tells me this: `Array<any>.concat(...items: ConcatArray<any>[]): any[]`. It looks like the default array functions are using `<any>` for their generics. Do you think you could just remove the generics from your custom function?

Comment: Sorry, as part of trying to get it to work I upgraded to Angular 9 and it broke a lot of stuff. It's just as well though, it's just a personal project, and I'm slowly rebuilding it better than ever. I will try this when I get there.